# How to reduce redirection chain to just one single redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I always redirect to https://www.example.ch **in one single redirect**.
Right now I get redirected multiple times to end up at my desired URL **while using my url alias**. Redirection chain looks like this:

```
Status Code URL IP  Page Type   Redirect Type   Redirect URL    
302 http://www.xn--exmple-icb.ch/   5.9.75.43   server_redirect temporary   https://xn--example-icb.ch/ 
302 https://xn--exmple-icb.ch/  5.9.75.43   server_redirect temporary   http://example.ch/ 
302 http://example.ch/  5.9.75.43   server_redirect temporary   https://example.ch/ 
301 https://example.ch/ 5.9.75.43   server_redirect permanent   https://www.example.ch/ 
200 https://www.example.ch/ 5.9.75.43   normal  none    none
```

As you might guess from the example, I have 2 registred domains. One is example.ch and the other ex**ä**mple.ch and everything should redirect to https:// www. example.ch in one single step.

How to configure this in my .htaccess?
I tried to do it like this

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.ch* [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.ex%C3%A4mple\.ch* [OR]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.ch/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But I assume I use [OR] wrong and/or don’t include a Rewrite Condition for [https://exämple.ch](https://ex%C3%A4mple.ch)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be getting issues from your `RewriteCond` as you noted yourself.

In pseudocode you are saying that you want to run the `RewriteRule` if:

The request is not https, or if it is not for www.example.ch or if it is not for www.exämple.ch.

So that then means that the redirect will fire not just on www.exämple.ch but also for www.example.ch.

Try this setup instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.ch*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.ch/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=6d58df20-5e24-5c58-8ea8-f3bc1d57fda5

Comment: thanks! I understand and it works great. Now It seems that the DNS setup somehow redirects my exämple URL before .htaccess is read. In the backend I have configured 2 "Websites" and set a tick at "Automatically set up DNS for this website." Might this causing additional redirects for the Domain with umlaut? (In case it is allowed to post my testsite: www.geländespiele.ch is my problem case)

Comment: Whatever it's doing, it isn't caused by that ruleset - maybe worth reposting this question on https://serverfault.com/